# What happens if the host quits a game you're in?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I know that MH3U doesn't support transferring the host, so if the host quits, the game ends. Does this mean that the game ends instantly, as soon as the host is gone?

Do you get a chance to save when this happens? If you're mid-mission, do you get to keep any items you've collected so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the host quits you are automatically transferred to single player.

While not in a quest, you just reload the UI and you spawn in the single player lobby. Everything you did (bought something or changed something in your box) is still done.

During a quest the others will leave the quest and let you alone. The monster still has the same amount of live left and you still have the same items with you as you had before (even traps and bombs are still placed) but you won't get the other Shakalaka (Cha-Cha or Kayamba).